# How to convert date to milliseconds by javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have multiple date's for example(25-12-2017) i need them to be converted to milliseconds by javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to use year, month and day as parameters on `new Date`

> new Date(year, month [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);

You can prepare your date string by using a function.

Note: Month is 0-11, that is why `m-1`

Here is a snippet:

```js
function prepareDate(d) {
  [d, m, y] = d.split("-"); //Split the string
  return [y, m - 1, d]; //Return as an array with y,m,d sequence
}

let str = "25-12-2017";
let d = new Date(...prepareDate(str));

console.log(d.getTime());
```

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't the *prepareDate* function just return a Date?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var dateTokens = "2018-03-13".split("-");
//creating date object from specified year, month, and day
var date1 = new Date(dateTokens[0], dateTokens[1] - 1, dateTokens[2]);
//creating date object from specified date string
var date2 = new Date("2018-03-13");

console.log("Date1 in milliseconds: ", date1.getTime());
console.log("Date2 in milliseconds: ", date1.getTime());

console.log("Date1: ", date1.toString());
console.log("Date2: ", date2.toString());
```

Comment: Note that the time value returned for the two approaches is different by your timezone offset (there's an error in your code). Don't use the built-in parser.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using vanilla javascript, you can also use many libraries to get more functions.

like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) etc

For example, use moment.js you can convert date to milliseconds by `moment('25-12-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY').valueOf()`, more elegant and powerful than vanilla javascript.

Comment: See [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) In particular, an answer should answer the question per the section *Answer the question*. Imagine asking a question about how to do something in the DOM in plain script and all you get are answers like "use a library like jQuery or Prototype.js" or "use a framework like react or angular".